# I'm having trouble writing a console application to create a simple program to solve a math equation for superannuation

Tags: c++

Could some one help me with this?
I've racked my head over an hour and I can't get it to work.
This is in `C++` and I've been learning for a little bit but I'm still new...

```
int main()
{
 double rate, amount,time, S;

    cout << "Insert the time of the super: ";
    cin >> time;

    cout << "Insert the rate (as a decimal, eg 1% AKA 101% = 1.01): ";
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Insert the amount $: ";
    cin >> amount;

    S =("amount * (rate ^ time - 1)", pow(rate,time));
    cin >> S;

    cout << "The total amount is: " << "S /(rate - 1)" << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

i dont get a compile error but i can never get an answer from it

Answer (score 4):

You "never get a result" because you're setting S to the result of `pow` with comma operator weirdness then assigning to it again with the line

```
cin >> S;
```

which is waiting for you to input another number.

You have two main problems. Here is the updated code with comments on the altered parts:

```
int main()
{
    double rate, amount,time, S;

    cout << "Insert the time of the super: ";
    cin >> time;

    cout << "Insert the rate (as a decimal, eg 1% AKA 101% = 1.01): ";
    cin >> rate;

    cout << "Insert the amount $: ";
    cin >> amount;

    S = amount * pow(rate, time - 1); // take away the quotes and don't make pow seperate

    cout << "The total amount is: " << (S /(rate - 1)) << endl; // do the calculation and output it

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Remember that things inside quotes `"like this"` are string literals, so `"4 * 4"` is a string but `4 * 4` (see the absence of quotes) does multiplication which yields the number `16`.

Comment: I think that the - 1 is supposed to be grouped as pow(rate, time - 1) rather than pow(rate, time) - 1.  I could be wrong about this, though.

Comment: @template yeah I think you're right, it looks that way, mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should assign values to S the way you are doing it. S is declared as double and you are assinging a string to it initially. And when you output the result you are also enclosing the calculation in quotes. You should simply cout << S / (rate-1); // without quotes or cout will simply output the string

Comment: He wasn't assigning a string to it, he was assigning a double because `pow` returns a double and the comma operator "discards" the first expression.